# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

My Spring moot application was working fine from my local. But all of a sudden I am getting the below error when I start my tomcat server from STS. I am clueless why am getting this error.

The error details,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
    org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java)
    org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMultiCaster.java)
    org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeneres(AbstractApplicationEventMultiCaster.java)
    ....
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    ....
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringAppliccation.java 362)
    at org.Springframework.boot.ApringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.Springframework.boot.ApringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.Springframework.boot.ApringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at com.test.Application.main(Application.java)
```

Am using java 8 and it is a Spring Boot project of version 2.4.2. I even tried to delete all my jars from the .m2 folder and installed them again. But the same issue, am facing.

Please help me to get a solution for this issue.

Comment: I doubt all your jars are from 2.4.2. Looks like you are using incompatible versions, without seeing your dependencies (pom or build file) this will be impossible to pin-point. But something is pulling in an incompatible version.

Answer (score -1):

it can be started normally after removal excess dependence in pom.xml
`<!--dependency>  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>  </dependency-->  <dependency>  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>  </dependency> <dependency>  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  </dependency>`

Comment: Please do not comment you own answer, make an edit.

Comment: Used comment to explain own answer.